# Adding Constraint Dynamically to a function

Tags: functional-programming, purescript

Is there any way I can add a constraint to a type class function dynamically?

Let's say my type class takes a function of type

```
type FieldTraverseFn :: Row Type -> (Type -> Type) -> Type
type FieldTraverseFn row m = forall sym a row'
                              .  IsSymbol sym 
                              => Row.Cons sym a row' row
                              => Proxy sym 
                              -> m Unit
```

and my type class is defined like,

```
class TraverseRecord :: RL.RowList Type -> Row Type -> Row Type -> (Type -> Type) -> Constraint
class (Monad m) <= TraverseRecord rl row wholeRow m | rl -> row where 
    traverseRecord :: FieldTraverseFn wholeRow m 
                   -> Proxy rl
                   -> Proxy wholeRow
                   -> m Unit
```

In the place where I'm calling `traverseRecord` the function that i'm passing has some additional constraint... because of it I can't call `traverseRecord`,

Let's say, I'm calling my function like,

```
logFields :: forall row wholeRow rl
            . (RL.RowToList row rl) 
            => TraverseRecord rl row row Effect 
            => (Record row)
            -> Effect Unit
logFields rec = traverseRecord myTraverseFn (Proxy :: Proxy rl) (Proxy :: Proxy row)
              where 
                myTraverseFn = Debug.traceM <<< reflectSymbol
```

The above works fine, but if I want to change `myTraverseFn` like, it is failing

```
myTraverseFn :: forall sym a row'
                              . IsSymbol sym 
                              => Row.Cons sym a row' row 
                              => Show a
                              => Proxy sym 
                              -> Effect Unit
                myTraverseFn pxy = do 
                      let a = Record.get pxy rec
                      Debug.traceM $ (reflectSymbol pxy) <> (show a)
```

It is failing because of the additional `Show a` constraint.

If I add the `Show a` to my type class it will work fine... But I don't want to do that..
Is there any way I can extend the constraint of a function defined in type class in some way?

Like the function that I'm passing has all the constraint that the type class function wants but it has some additional constraint.

I can understand that the compiler isn't sure about my constraint, but How can I make it work? is it possible?

Comment: If your function requires the constraint, then it has to ultimately come from _somewhere_. What do you expect it to come from?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I want the value `a` of my fields to depend on the constraint that my function has, (let's say my function has contraint Show a, then my type class also has to be able to work with that contraint) its more like how `purescript-heterogeneous` works... I'm not sure how to do it..

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Comment: I specify the constraint and I specify the constraint(which my fields have)